# Zend Framework site and Magento shopping cart integration

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, integration

I am working on a community portal built on zend framework. Where in one of module I have products for online sale. I have to implement a shopping cart for online selling.

As we know Magento is built on zend framework. How can I integrate it with my site ?

Which one will be better? integrating Magento  or writing own shopping cart code ?

Is there is any other open source cart which we can easily integrate with zend framework?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write our own shopping cart script.

You can take help of link below:

http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-shopping-cart-using-zend-framework-1

We know magento is built on ZF. But integrating it in your site will not be easy. Magento table structure will be different then your site. You will need to do lot of work for integration. And  if your site is in middle like user and products modules are already completed. Then might be you need to rework totally for them.

Best way is make your own shopping cart system according to your needs.